# Display a custom meta field in Woocommerce admin orders list and make it searchable

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, orders

We use the following function.php code below to offer a multi choice field in checkout. We add it to the order page and include it in the email.

How can we include it in the ORDERs overview admin page as well, make it searchable and sortable ?

```
// add select box for platform used at checkout
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'wps_add_select_checkout_field');
function wps_add_select_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    echo '<h3>'.__('').'</h3>';
    woocommerce_form_field( 'platform', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array( 'wps-drop' ),
        'label'         => __( 'On which platform will you be using it?' ),
        'options'       => array(
            'blank'     => __( '-- Choose an option --', 'wps' ),
            'app1'  => __( 'app1', 'wps' ),
            'app2'  => __( 'app2', 'wps' ),
            'app3'  => __( 'app3', 'wps' )
        )
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'platform' ) );
}

// Process the checkout
 add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wps_select_checkout_field_process');
 function wps_select_checkout_field_process() {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ($_POST['platform'] == "blank")
        wc_add_notice( '<strong>Please select your primary trading platform that you will be using with our strategy</strong>', 'error' );
 }


 // Update the order meta with field value
 add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'wps_select_checkout_field_update_order_meta');
 function wps_select_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
     if ($_POST['platform']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'platform', esc_attr($_POST['platform']));
 }

 // Display field value on the order edition page
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'wps_select_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function wps_select_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Primary Platform').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'platform', true ) . '</p>';
}

// Add selection field value to emails
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'wps_select_order_meta_keys');
function wps_select_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
    $keys['platform:'] = 'platform';
    return $keys;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way to add a custom column 'Platform' in Admin WooCommerce Orders list and to add this custom field meta key in the search:

```
// ADDING A CUSTOM COLUMN TITLE TO ADMIN ORDER LIST
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_column', 12, 1 );
function custom_shop_order_column($columns)
{
    // Set "Actions" column after the new colum
    $action_column = $columns['order_actions']; // Set the title in a variable
    unset($columns['order_actions']); // remove  "Actions" column


    //add the new column "Platform"
    $columns['order_platform'] = '<span>'.__( 'Platform','woocommerce').'</span>'; // title

    // Set back "Actions" column
    $columns['order_actions'] = $action_column;

    return $columns;
}

// ADDING THE DATA FOR EACH ORDERS BY "Platform" COLUMN
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_order_list_column_content', 10, 2 );
function custom_order_list_column_content( $column, $post_id )
{

    // HERE get the data from your custom field (set the correct meta key below)
    $platform = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'platform', true );
    if( empty($platform)) $platform = '';

    switch ( $column )
    {
        case 'order_platform' :
            echo '<span>'.$platform.'</span>'; // display the data
            break;
    }
}

// MAKE 'PLATFORM' METAKEY SEARCHABLE IN THE SHOP ORDERS LIST
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 'platform_search_fields', 10, 1 );
function platform_search_fields( $meta_keys ){
    $meta_keys[] = 'platform';
    return $meta_keys;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme or in any plugin file).*

Tested and works.